# JavaScript - Is there a way to check if a string includes a keyword but only that keyword?

Tags: javascript, string

I'm currently using the string.includes() method to check for the keyword 'rally' in a string. But if I have the text 'Can I have a rally?', it will respond the same as 'Am I morally wrong?'. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can use a regular expression or some other method to determine that the characters before and after the word 'rally' are either a space, punctuation, the beginning of the string, or the end of the string. That makes sure that the word rally stands on its own and is not a substring of some other word.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 'Can I have a rally?'.match(/(\w+)/g).indexOf("rally") !== -1  // will return true


 'Am I morally wrong?'.match(/(\w+)/g).indexOf("rally") !== -1 // will return false
```

Answer (score 0):

## edit Using regular expressions

```
let text = "Am I mo rally wrong";

function searchText(searchOnString, searchText) {
  searchText = searchText.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
  return searchOnString.match(new RegExp("\\b"+searchText+"\\b", "i")) != null;
}

console.log(searchText(text, "rally"));
```

Comment: This will work badly if the `rally` is the first or last word in the sentence.

Comment: See the edit, using escaped regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

maybe you just add space. So **morally** gives false result. This checks the words possible each position into sentence also whole string is "rally".

```js
var string = "Can I have rally";

console.log(string==="rally" ? true : false || string.includes(' rally') || string.includes('rally ') || string.includes(' rally '));
```

Comment: this will be a false-negative if the whole string was 'rally'

Comment: See the edit@meta

Comment: Yeah, this would work. Still https://stackoverflow.com/a/48321982/299774 is much cleaner.